# How to strip/replace text in with selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm learning to do web scraping and i managed to pull data out of a webpage into excel file. But, it might be because of the item names that contain "," and this made the item names in the excel file to multiple columns.

I have tried using strip and replace elements in the list but it returns an error saying: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'replace'.

```
item = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h2[@class="list_title"]')
item = [i.replace(",","") for i in item]
price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="ads_price"]')
price = [p.replace("rm","") for p in price]
```

**expected result in excel file file:**
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2XdP.png) 
**actual result in excel file file:**
[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPQjN.png)

Answer (score 0):

The function find_elements_by_xpath returns a WebElement object, you will need to convert this to a string in order to use the replace function.

Depending on your use case you may want to reconsider using excel as your storage medium, unless this is the final step of your process.

Answer (score 0):

The portion of your code that you've included in your question isn't the portion that's relevant to the issue you're experiencing.

As CMMCD mentioned, I would also recommend skipping the binary excel format for the sake of simplicity, and use the built-in csv library instead. This will prevent unintended separators from splitting your cells

```
from csv import writer

# your data should be a list of lists
data = [['product1', 8.0], ['product2', 12.25]]  # etc, as an example

with open('your_output_file.csv', 'w') as file:
    mywriter = writer(file)
    for line in data:
        mywriter.writerow(line)
```

The docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html